# Can Passpoint X.509 certificates be used to MITM SSL connections on Passpoint networks?

Tags: authentication, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, wifi, x.509

Passpoint/Hotspot 2.0 public networks like LinkNYC require users to install X.509 certificates, for EAP authentication.

Can these certificates be used by the provider to execute man-in-the middle attacks between the user and HTTPS websites that the user is browsing?

Or, are certificates/CAs installed for EAP authentication different from the OS/browser's SSL certificate chain?

If the Passpoint AP provides a self-signed certificate or even a new root CA, does trusting these certificates open the client to MITM attacks while using HTTPS sites on that network?

Also, the screenshots provided by this LinkNYC user here : http://blog.alexflor.es/post/137705262900/linknyc-secure-gigabit-hotspot seem to suggest an entire chain upto a root is provided to be installed on the client. Is the entire chain presented simply because of the EAP-T(TLS) spec (as mentioned in the accepted answer here: [Why is a CA certificate required for EAP-TLS clients?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47932/why-is-a-ca-certificate-required-for-eap-tls-clients))?

Comment: I was not entirely sure how Passpoint worked, the writer of the blog I linked to (and the screenshots there) seemed to suggest that a new root CA cert was installed on the iPhone. I guess that threw me off.


What you said, along with the fact that Passpoint systems are required to use pre-defined certs makes much more sense now. It is *in fact* the client cert that is offered by the Passpoint AP to install on the client device.

Comment: Page 42 confirms it: https://www.wi-fi.org/download.php?file=/sites/default/files/private/Passpoint_R2_Deployment_Guidelines-v1%200.pdf

>"Passpoint supports user mobile device authentication using a client certificate (EAP-TLS).  The client certificate can be issued from any CA the SP prefers and is installed on the mobile device during the manufacturing process or provisioning process."

Comment: @garethTheRed, you should make your comment an answer so it can be upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

The certificates in your linked images are commercial certificates, therefore your device trusts those already by virtue of the fact that the commercial [root CA certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate) is in its trust store.

The certificate you installed is probably a [client certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate), which you use to authenticate yourself with the system.

It's my (limited) understanding that Passpoint systems must use [pre-defined certificates](http://www.wi-fi.org/certification/certificate-authority-vendors) as dictated to by the WiFi Alliance, and not ask you to install an additional root CA certificate in your trust store.