# Wireless EAP-TLS implementing on Medical Wireless Device

Tags: authentication, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, wireless

I am new to PKI, digital certificates etc and will be the first time to connect a medical wireless device to a wireless network using EAP-TLS.
I am connecting a medical wireless device to our customer's hospital wireless network with the below set up:

```
Root CA > Intermediate CA > Intermediate CA > User Certificate
```

Does the medical device require the entire chain, just the root CA, or just the intermediate chain?

Also, the medical wireless device that I have, have the following fields that needs to be filled out by the hospital's IT:

```
CA-CERT:
Client Cert:
Private Key:
Password:
```

I would presume the CA-CERT would contain the hospital's certificate issued to this device (possibly with the entire chain) but I am not really sure what the Client Cert, Private Key and Password will contain?

Comment: please browse a little bit before posting questions  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47932/why-is-a-ca-certificate-required-for-eap-tls-clients , still a am replying in answer for you

Comment: It would be wise to put the intermediates in the same CA Cert file, otherwise the device will be unable to build a trust chain back to the trust anchor (root certificate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CA-CERT:** *I would presume the CA-CERT would contain the hospital's certificate issued to this device (possibly with the entire chain)*

No, this is actually the root CA certificate for which the server will send a certificate chain to authenticate to the client. This prevents the client from connecting to a fake access point.

**Client Cert:** A certificate chain from a root CA the server trusts that shows that the owner of the private key (next) is actually this device.

**Private Key:** The private key that only this device knows and which identifies the device.

**Password:** This is a password which protects the private key.

So to clarify:
The server and client both authenticate to each other.

**CA-CERT** will be used to authenticate the server to the client.

**Client Cert**, **Private Key** and **Password** will be used to authenticate the client to the server.

Comment: Hi Elias, can I ask what the "Identity" field is, and why the Password field is grayed out for this medical device?  I have always thought that these are the user created in AD?

Answer (score 0):

In general as in most of the cases generic terminology means :-

CA-CERT : It is the Root certificate of the certificate chain the EAP server is going  to test , it helps user to protect from EVIL-TWIN type of attack by not allowing TLS handshake from non trusted Authentication servers

Client Cert : - It is the Chain of certificate( or individual certificate) that you will be sending to Authentication server for EAP negotiation , depth of chain depends on how you AS is expecting

Private key :- It is the secret key to protect you Private key , used while deploying your user certificate on device